# why date('d/m/y',strtotime(return_time()) not working in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

i've a function, which sends current date and time of asia region

```
function return_time()
{
    if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    }
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s a');
}
```

and i'm trying to show today's date to the user, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong, here is what i'm doing

```
echo date('d/m/y',strtotime(return_time()))
```

here is what i'm getting in output

```
01/01/70
```

Comment: Is not kind of obviously when you echoing your date as `d/m/y` although you returning a function with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s a')`?

Answer (score 4):

Having the `a` formatter in `date()` outputs an invalid date string which causes `strtotime()` to return `false` which causes `date()` to think it is zero which equates to the Unix Epoch which is Jan 1, 1970.

The `a` is necessary since your time is already in 24 hour format. Remove it.

I don't know why you have it so convoluted, though. If you just want to print out today's date just do:

```
echo date('d/m/y');
```

Comment: I think you mean "unnecessary" in that sentence. Though I can't make an edit for two character changes.

Comment: actually our date and time should be in IST so that is making sure it returns the time and data according to IST :)

Comment: That's easy enough to do. Just set the timezone either because this call to date() or set it in your config file so it's always set.